# Excel 2016 bug?

Tags: excel, vba

I am experiencing a replicable problem with Excel 2016.

I've created an application, that will work flawlessly in Excel 2010, but not in Excel 2016. In the app, the user selects a workbook from which they will be asked to select multiple, seperate ranges.

There's a form with multiple buttons, each of which asks them to select a range related to a paricular item from the previously selected workbook.

When the button is clicked, the selected workbook should be active so they can select the range. This is the case in Excel 2010, but not in Excel 2016.

In Excel 2016, the workbook that the userform exists in keeps displaying instead of the selected workbook.

To replicate the problem, the below steps can be followed:

- Open Excel 2016
- Create 2x workbooks
- In Workbook 1, create a userform
- Create a command button with the below code behind it.
- Activate Workbook1
- Initialise the form and click the button
- Select any range (Workbook2 should be active)
- Click the button again...

The problem: Workbook2 is no longer active when selecting a second range. (Excel 2010 will keep Workbook2 active - everytime).

Other than selecting the Switch Windows function, the only way I've manged to select a second range from Workbook2, is to click over the Cancel button and release the mouse elsewhere, i.e., don't actually click Cancel.

This will display Workbook2, however, you cannot select a range yet; a range can only be selected after clicking into the dialog box (from what I've discovered).

Also, I've just noticed that if you initialise the userform with Workbook2 being active, when you click the button, Workbook1 will activate instead.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rng As Range

    Me.Hide

    ' Windows(2).Activate ' edited for correctness
    Workbooks("Book2").Activate

    On Error Resume Next

    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select range", "Select Range", Type:=8)

    On Error GoTo 0

    Me.Show
End Sub
```

Could this be down to Microsoft moving from MDI to SDI for Excel 2013 and above?

More importantly, how do I get around this issue?

Comment: Isn't the correct code for activating "Workbooks" `Workbooks(2).Activate`? Or even `Workbooks("Name").Activate`?

Comment: Order of items in `Windows` changes as order of actual windows changes. `Windows(1)` is always the active window, so your `Windows(2)` will yield different windows depending on what was active last time, and it should certainly not give same window twice in a row given that after the previous call another window became number 1. I believe this is how it worked in Excel from the start.

Comment: Yes, but it was simpler and quicker to replicate the issue with this simple code. The problem will still occur whether you use Workbooks or Windows.

Comment: To get around you can try: remove `Me.Hide`, replace `Me.Show` with Workbook1 activation.